# SQL: Copy the result of a TOP-1-SELECT statement into @LocalVariables (for a following UPDATE statement in a stored procedure)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, local-variables

Inside a UPDATE statement I need several values of a (1-ROW-)SELECT statement.
So I need to copy the result fields of this SELECT statement to local variables in order to use them in the following UPDATE statement.

```
DECLARE @VoltageSum DECIMAL(18, 2);
DECLARE @CurrentSum DECIMAL(18, 2);
DECLARE @PowerSum DECIMAL(18, 2);

SELECT
  SUM(Value1_Voltage) AS Voltage_Sum,
  SUM(Value2_Current) AS Current_Sum,
  SUM(Value3_Power) AS Power_Sum,
  COUNT(*) AS NumberOfRecords
FROM EnergyMonitor
WHERE TimeType < 2

SET @Voltage_Sum = Voltage_Sum;   <-- this line is not working...

UPDATE EnergyMonitor SET
  NumberOfValues = @NumberOfRecords,
  Value1_Voltage = @VoltageSum / @NumberOfRecords,
  Value2_Current = @CurrentSum / @NumberOfRecords,
  Value3_Power = @PowerSum / @NumberOfRecords,
WHERE TimeType=2 AND TimeValue=@Minute
```

Unfortunately I am not able to copy the result of the SELECT statement inside local SQL variables.
How can I solve that problem?

Answer (score 1):

use a sub-query to calculate the value and then `CROSS JOIN` to your table and perform the `UPDATE`.

```
UPDATE e
SET
      NumberOfValues = c.NumberOfRecords,
      Value1_Voltage = c.VoltageSum / c.NumberOfRecords,
      Value2_Current = c.CurrentSum / c.NumberOfRecords,
      Value3_Power   = c.PowerSum / c.NumberOfRecords,
FROM  
      EnergyMonitor e
      CROSS JOIN
      (
          SELECT
                SUM(Value1_Voltage) AS Voltage_Sum,
                SUM(Value2_Current) AS Current_Sum,
                SUM(Value3_Power) AS Power_Sum,
                COUNT(*) AS NumberOfRecords
          FROM  
                EnergyMonitor
          WHERE 
                TimeType < 2
      ) c
WHERE 
      e.TimeType  = 2 
AND   e.TimeValue = @Minute
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this :-

```
DECLARE @VoltageSum DECIMAL(18, 2);
DECLARE @CurrentSum DECIMAL(18, 2);
DECLARE @PowerSum DECIMAL(18, 2);
DECLARE @NumberOfRecords INT;



    SELECT
      @VoltageSum = SUM(Value1_Voltage) ,
      @CurrentSum = SUM(Value2_Current) ,
      @PowerSum = SUM(Value3_Power),
      @NumberOfRecords = COUNT(*) AS NumberOfRecords
    FROM EnergyMonitor
    WHERE TimeType < 2
```

OR Remove the count from the query if not being used

```
 SELECT
          @VoltageSum = SUM(Value1_Voltage) ,
          @CurrentSum = SUM(Value2_Current) ,
          @PowerSum = SUM(Value3_Power)
        FROM EnergyMonitor
        WHERE TimeType < 2
```

Comment: This is not working: "A SELECT statement that assigns a value to a variable must not be combined with data retrieval operations."

Comment: Okay I got the issue, try to remove the number of records from the query if not being used, or add another variable and assign the value to that variable as well

Answer (score -1):

I solved it using a cursor:

```
DECLARE @VoltageSum DECIMAL(18, 2);
DECLARE @CurrentSum DECIMAL(18, 2);
DECLARE @PowerSum DECIMAL(18, 2);
DECLARE @MyCursor CURSOR;

SET @MyCursor = CURSOR FOR
SELECT
  SUM(Value1_Voltage) AS Voltage_Sum,
  SUM(Value2_Current) AS Current_Sum,
  SUM(Value3_Power) AS Power_Sum,
  COUNT(*) AS NumberOfRecords
FROM EnergyMonitor
WHERE TimeType < 2

-- Copy the result of the last SELECT statement into @LocalSqlVariables
OPEN @MyCursor
FETCH NEXT FROM @MyCursor INTO
  @VoltageSum,
  @CurrentSum,
  @PowerSum, 
  @NumberOfRecords;
CLOSE @MyCursor

UPDATE EnergyMonitor SET
  NumberOfValues = @NumberOfRecords,
  Value1_Voltage = @VoltageSum / @NumberOfRecords,
  Value2_Current = @CurrentSum / @NumberOfRecords,
  Value3_Power = @PowerSum / @NumberOfRecords,
WHERE TimeType=2 AND TimeValue=@Minute
```

Comment: Doesn't make sense to use a `CURSOR` here, you could just as well do `SELECT @NumberOfRecords = COUNT(*)...`

Comment: @Charlieface: My solution works perfectly, which is the reason I don't want to delete this answer, but I have to admit that your idea is the easier one.